# How to align the toolbar with each rotation in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, toolbar, xcode4.3, uitoolbar

XCODE 4.3.2 USER

Hi All,

Does anyone know how to align their toolbar properly with each rotation? In a view controller I have a navigation bar at the top and a toolbar at the bottom. Currently, they are both the same size, but when I do a horizontal rotation, the navigation bar has accommodated for the sizing and has made itself smaller, whereas the toolbar at the bottom is the same as it was in the vertical position. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I pulled a toolbar from the Objects pane and then dragged it into the view controller in case that info is helpful.

THX,
:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have autosizing set properly for your new "`UIToolbar`" object.  It should look like this in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work. Does it work for you in your simulator?

Comment: Delete the app from your simulator and/or device and clean your project then re-build & re-install.  Sometimes xib files don't get updated in the built apps between updates.

Comment: Michael, I have tried that as well. I even tried doing this fresh in a new project. XCode 4.3.2 does not use xib files as a side note. :(